# enumerate is not indenting correctly

Tags: enumerate, indentation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[i]
  \item $|\langle v, w \rangle| \leq \norm{v} \norm{w}$
  \item \norm{v + w} \leq \norm{v} + \norm{w}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm trying to get the second entry (ii) to align with the first (i) entry. Somehow enumerate is not indenting correctly?

Comment: You're missing `$` signs in the second item. First remove the errors and then retry. You also have an undefined `\norm` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples produces the following console output (at the `?` prompt I typed “Return”):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8   \item $|\langle v, w \rangle| \leq \norm
                                              {v} \norm{w}$
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 ...$|\langle v, w \rangle| \leq \norm{v} \norm
                                                  {w}$
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \norm 

l.9   \item \norm
                 {v + w} \leq \norm{v} + \norm{w}
? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.9   \item \norm{v + w} \leq
                              \norm{v} + \norm{w}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.9   \item \norm{v + w} \leq \norm
                                   {v} + \norm{w}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.9   \item \norm{v + w} \leq \norm{v} + \norm
                                              {w}
? 

! LaTeX Error: Command \end{enumerate} invalid in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 \end{enumerate}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 \end{enumerate}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 \end{enumerate}

? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.10 \end{enumerate}

?
```

There are ten errors.

1. `\norm` is not a standard command and you have to define it if you want to use it.
2. `\le` is a math command, so it needs to be inside `$...$` (for inline math mode) or to be in a math display environment.
3. If you skip errors, TeX will recover as best it can, in this case it cannot find a real enumeration item.

Here's a fixed code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} % necessary for math
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[i]
  \item $|\langle v, w \rangle| \leq \norm{v} \norm{w}$
  \item $\norm{v + w} \leq \norm{v} + \norm{w}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]